# Using match on array field before unwind

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have the following document structure:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a16b7cf930a1e000465d1c5"),
    "trackerId" : ObjectId("5a16b7b8930a1e000465d1c1"),
    "trackingEvents" : [ 
        {
            "type" : "checkin",
            "timestamp" : ISODate("2017-11-23T11:57:43.710Z"),
        }, 
        {
            "type" : "connectivity",
            "timestamp" : ISODate("2017-11-23T11:57:47.011Z"),
        }, 
        {
            "type" : "power",
            "timestamp" : ISODate("2017-11-23T11:57:47.036Z"),
        }
    ]
}
```

I would like to setup a query to count number of `trackingEvents` with `"type":"power"` grouped by day for all `trackingEvents` happened < 1 month ago. And have the following query which works fine, except for the fact that it is not fast enough:

```
db.getCollection('trackerEvents').aggregate(    [
        {$unwind: "$trackingEvents"},
        {$match:
            {
            "trackingEvents.type": "power",
            "trackingEvents.timestamp": {
                    "$gt": {
                        "$humanTime": "1 month ago" //redash operator
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "$group": {
                "_id": {
                    "$dateToString": {
                        "format": "%Y-%m-%d",
                        "date": "$trackingEvents.timestamp"
                    }
                },
                count: {$sum: 1}
            }
        },
        ,
        { $sort : { "_id":1 } }
    ])
```

However, this query did not pass the code review as my colleague suggested to swap `$match` and `$unwind` operators so that `$match` goes before `$unwind` in order to increase perfomance of the query. If I swap these two operators, I get different results, could someone please suggest how is it possible to `$match` array elements of the document before `$unwind`?

Thanks!

Comment: What's your MongoDB server version?

Comment: You can e.g. have the match before AND after the unwind. The first stages can then use indexes. Depends on your data, of course.

Comment: @chridam MongoDB 3.2

Comment: You can also use the `$filter` operator for arrays. You could already filter the results out before you unwind

Answer (score 2):

You could use the **[`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/aggregation/match/)** operator as a way to filter early the documents then **[`$filter`](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/#exp._S_filter)** at array level before **[`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/)**:

```
var oneMonthAgo = new Date();
oneMonthAgo.setMonth(oneMonthAgo.getMonth()-1);
// var oneMonthAgo = moment().subtract(1, "months").unix();

db.getCollection('trackerEvents').aggregate([
    { 
        "$match": { 
            "trackingEvents.type": "power",
            "trackingEvents.timestamp": { "$gt": oneMonthAgo }
        } 
    },
    {
        "$project": {
            "trackingEvents": {
                "$filter": {
                    "input": "$trackingEvents",
                    "as": "event",
                    "cond": {
                        "$and": [
                            { "$eq": ["$$event.type", "power"] },
                            { "$gt": ["$$event.timestamp", oneMonthAgo] }
                        ]
                    }
                }               
            }
        }
    },
    { "$unwind": "$trackingEvents" },
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": {
                "$dateToString": {
                    "format": "%Y-%m-%d",
                    "date": "$trackingEvents.timestamp"
                }
            },
            "count": { "$sum": 1}
        }
    },
    { "$sort": { "_id": 1 } }
]);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, can you please give a hint - how can I group by day these results? Should I remove $size and add $group operator to the query?

Comment: @AndreyYaskulsky Had completely misunderstood the question earlier, my bad. The update should have better performance as it has early document and field filtering pipelines before the `$unwind`.